# boost::asio::async_resolve Problem

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, c++11, boost-asio

I'm in the process of constructing a Socket class that uses `boost::asio`.  To start with, I made a `connect` method that took a host and a port and resolved it to an IP address.  This worked well, so I decided to look in to `async_resolve`.  However, my callback always gets an error code of `995` (using the same destination host/port as when it worked synchronously).

**code**:

Function that starts the resolution:

```
  // resolve a host asynchronously
  template<typename ResolveHandler>
  void resolveHost(const String& _host, Port _port, ResolveHandler _handler) const
  {
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ret;
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(_host, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(_port));
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(m_IOService);
   r.async_resolve(query, _handler);
  }; // eo resolveHost
```

Code that calls this function:

```
  void Socket::connect(const String& _host, Port _port)
  {
   // Anon function for resolution of the host-name and asynchronous calling of the above
   auto anonResolve = [this](const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode, 
           boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver_iterator _epIt)
   {
    // raise event
    onResolve.raise(SocketResolveEventArgs(*this, !_errorCode ? (*_epIt).host_name() : String(""), _errorCode));

    // perform connect, calling back to anonymous function
    if(!_errorCode)
     connect(*_epIt);
   };

   // Resolve the host calling back to anonymous function
   Root::instance().resolveHost(_host, _port, anonResolve);

  }; // eo connect
```

The `message()` function of the `error_code` is:

```
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

And my `main.cpp` looks like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 morse::Root root;
 TextSocket s;
 s.connect("somehost.com", 1234);
 while(true)
 {
  root.performIO(); // calls io_service::run_one()
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `resolver` object is going out of scope, move it to a member of the `Socket` class and make `resolveHost` a method rather than free function.

This happens because `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver` is [a typedef of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/resolver.html) a `basic_resolver`, [which inherits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver.html) from `basic_io_object`.  When the resolver goes out of scope, `~basic_io_object()` [destroys](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html) the underlying resolver service before your [handler can be posted](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve/overload1.html).

> Regardless of whether the asynchronous
>   operation completes immediately or
>   not, the handler will not be invoked
>   from within this function. Invocation
>   of the handler will be performed in a
>   manner equivalent to using
>   boost::asio::io_service::post().

Comment: Thankyou very much, that should have been completely obvious :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice no problem, glad to help. Sometimes a second set of eyes is all you need.