# Async Resolve with Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio, resolve

I'm trying to **asynchronously** resolve a ftp host using Boost.Asio.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class FtpSession {
public:
    void Connect(std::string& host) {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(host, "ftp");

        resolver.async_resolve(query,
            boost::bind(&FtpSession::OnResolve, this, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
                    boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
    }

private:
    void OnResolve(const boost::system::error_code& err, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator) {
        if (!err)
        {
            std::cout << "resolved!";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "error.";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    FtpSession session;
    std::string host("ftp.remotesensing.org");

    session.Connect(host);

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason, when I execute it, it just doesn't print anything:

```
alon@alon-GA-73PVM-S2H:~/Desktop$ g++ -o test -lboost_system test.cc
alon@alon-GA-73PVM-S2H:~/Desktop$ ./test
alon@alon-GA-73PVM-S2H:~/Desktop$
```

No errors or warnings at the compilation though.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `io_service.run()` to actually do the work methinks. Think of the `async_resolve` as a request in a request queue - you need something (the `io_service`) to process the requests in the queue, and to do that, you actually need to `run()` it! In this case, it will see one request, execute it, call the handler and then exit.

Comment: Thanks! Does `io_service.run()` execute this on the current thread? If yes, is there any way to do this non-blocking?

Comment: Yes it does, you need to create a `boost::thread`, and then `bind` to the `run` of the `io_service` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your `io_service` and `ip::tcp::resolver` object are going out of scope. Move both of them into members of the `FtpSession` class, then invoke `io_service::run` inside of main after  `session.Connect(host)` to start the event loop.

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636608/boostasioasync-resolve-problem/4636764#4636764) a few days ago that may help you as well.